# Play a sound with Firebase when browser receives a notification while running in the background

Tags: javascript, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I would like to know how to play a sound with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) 
when the web browser such as Chrome, Firefox, etc. receives a notification message while running in the background.

notification while running in the background
[image]
To receive a message while the app is in the background, in FCM, call `setBackgroundMessageHandler` in the service worker `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
 messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
      console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
      ...
      return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
    });
```

However, Audio Object `window.AudioContext` can not be called in service worker. In addition, The notification property [`Notification.sound`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/sound) is not currently supported in any browser.

I would like to know how to play a sound with FCM when the app is in the background.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

While sounds are not currently supported, you should be able to vibrate a user's device when showing a notification from inside of a service worker. That might be sufficient to get their attention. (If you really need to...)

Here's an excerpt from a [live sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/notifications/vibrate.html):

```
registration.showNotification('Vibration Sample', {
  body: 'Your title here.',
  icon: 'path/to/icon.png',
  vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
  tag: 'vibration-sample'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment. I want to play sound in PC web browser. Maybe, the vibration works on only mobile device's browser. Sorry for lack of description.

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to add notification sound for background message since showNotification doesn't have sound property.

You wont be able to add function inside the event listener as well, when called from service worker as the service worker doesn't have access to window from here.

You can add vibrate to showNotification, which again is only allowed for mobile device.

Comment: Thanks! I have this exact issue, a user on my mobile app is trying to do a video call to a different type of user on my web app. If that web app user isn't currently using the web app in the "foreground" i'd love for the system notification to play a sound. The weird part is, if you use node-notifier via something like Gulp it can easily issue a system notification and play a sound.

Answer (score -4):

You should be able to add a function inside the event listener for push in the service-worker and just have it play a sound.