# How to Play Sound when receive FCM notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

i use FCM to send/receive notification on my site
everything work fine.

I use

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
```

to receive notification when user is online and i play sound using

```
var src = 'bing.mp3';
var c = document.createElement('audio'); 
c.src=src; c.play();
```

it's work fine , but not working when tab is inactive.
because notifications received throw services worker

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
```

is there any way to play sound when receive notifications and tab is inactive ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784303/play-a-sound-with-firebase-when-browser-receives-a-notification-while-running-in

Comment: the two answer ins't correct and here i said to play sound when receive notifications when user is online only but browser tab is inactive ... because if he is offline it's not possible to play sound

Comment: There may be ways but remember that the chrome browser won't play sounds until the user has interacted (read clicked) after the page load.